How to deploy microfrontends in Angular separately within a Monorepo?
We currently have a monorepo project that is standalone, and we want to modularize the app into individual modules that can be worked on separately and deployed independently. We are using Nx and aim to leverage its capabilities along with Module Federation to achieve this. My idea is to create microfrontends while keeping the monorepo, but my team insists that we need different repositories for different modules and libraries since they believe there isn't a way to deploy them separately while keeping them in one repo.
I've read articles suggesting the use of Nx affected to handle this, but I would like to hear your suggestions on how to approach this while maintaining the monorepo. Specifically, if we merge changes to the develop branch, how can we ensure that only module 2 is deployed and not module 1? An example deploy YAML file, an article or an existing project setup would be very helpful.

Have you considered using a polyrepo inside the monorepo? The key is to use git submodules. For example, an angular app can be a git submodule that lives inside the monorepo, the monorepo is pushed in a branch that triggers the pipeline (uses git submodule foreach for pull changes), the pipeline uses nx affected to release the libraries, and the apps modules should be pushed into another branch that triggers another pipeline for each app. Tools that can help are : "@manypkg/cli", "@semantic-release/*" a basic example of a repo: https://github.com/oscarludick/test-app

Hi @OscarLudick thank you for your answer, you actually touched on one of the point that I was curious about, how is this different from completely different repos, for me its important that these modules that can be worked on and deployed separately still share the same versioning thus monorepo, how do the submodule affect this?

The big difference from completely different repos is that you can share nx and tools features even when your repos are separated, things like configurations (prettier, semantic release, husky, node_modules) all in a single workspace, but they are deployed separately (excluding unnecessary code, improving ci/cd performance, tag versions for apps/libs), and the monorepo acts as the main repository for version control , updating the references of each submodule. Maybe is not what are you looking for, but i hope it gives you some ideas of what approach do you want to implement.

@OscarLudick got it, thank you

We are using NX monorepo with micro front-ends architecture. We can deploy 4 different apps out of it. One that combines all FEs (A, B, C, D) and it's authenticated, one which provides A and B without authentication, one which provides standalone C without authentication and standalone, authenticated D. It's a matter of quick configuration

@mat.hudak could you provide and example of the pipeline configs you have?

Hey @OscarLudick I think my setup will be quite similar to yours, could you answer a couple of questions I've got for your repo?
1: If you intend to work in different parts of the project at once then you'll have to clone the individual libs/modules and work on them separately or is it possible only via the project monorepo?
2: Deploy of module and libs is done when we push on their respective branches or is it possible from the main repo to do this, related to the first question

@ÇlirimMurati from where i work, we have a more complex setup of the basic example i gave you. So yes, we clone all the submodules to work them separately (git submodule update --init --recursive), with the help of git hooks (husky), when a commit is made at the monorepo level (it contains the git references) the hook is triggered and with the help of a script we were able to automate the commits/stash/pull/push in all the submodules, this is pushed in a branch that does not trigger any deploy in the submodules.

@ÇlirimMurati only a pipeline is triggered at the monorepo, with the help of nx affected we compile/build/publish the libraries or apps, and if necessary, all submodule changes are pushed into another branch that triggers another pipeline independently for each submodule that can do the deploy of the applications.
